# MongoDB $or acting like $and

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to count the number of documents having either a non-empty `features` array or a non-empty `description` string like so:

```
collection.find({
    $or: [{
        features: {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}},
        description: {$exists: true, $ne: ""}
    }],
}).count()
```

Weirdly enough (to me), adding the second expression to the `$or` array reduces the number of matches. 556 documents have a non-empty `features`array, and 294 have a non-empty description. Combining the two using `$or` results in 214 matches, and they all seem to have both description *and* features. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your 2 conditions are in the same item of the $or array. So basically, you're filtering for documents satisfy both conditions. I think the second condition should be in the second item of the array, like this :

```
collection.find({
    $or: [
    {
        features: {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}},
       
    }, 
    {
        description: {$exists: true, $ne: ""}
    }
],
}).count()
```

Comment: Aah that's a proper facepalm moment right there! Thanks for your sharp eye and kind answer.